# Wait for The Rails 3 Way or any other similar book?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am thinking of getting The Rails 3 Way to get a better understanding of Rails 3 (I'm a beginner), are there any other books similar that would help me understand Rails 3 a little better?

Also are there are any good Rails 3 books released yet? I am currently looking into buying a peepcode rails 3 screencast.

Answer (score 4):

The most recent edition of Agile web development with Rails covers Rails 3. One of coauthors is DHH, and I warmly recommend that book (I studied Rails 1.2 from it long ago).

Comment: This book is currently in beta, scheduled for paper release in January 2011. Additionally, you can purchase the beta e-book if you can't wait at http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails

Comment: I learned a lot with the Agile book years ago.  I've purchased the latest beta e-book and it's still pretty good.  I bought the first "The Rails Way" book, maybe things have improved, but I found it more of a reference for intermediate/advance Rails programmers.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl at http://railstutorial.org. It covers Rails 3 and behavior-(test-)driven development. I highly recommend this series.

Comment: Thanks I did not notice that it was updated for rails 3. I only saw it when it was still rails 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you live by a public library, go and checkout every Rails book there (starting with the most recent ones.) And throw in a Ruby book while you're at it. Seriously, the library has been my best resource. Even older books have been very helpful. So what if they're Rails 2 books?  You'll still learn a lot. And if you don't like how a book is written, stop reading it and go get another one.

I looked through the current edition of The Rails Way (obtained from the library) a number of months ago. At that time, it was a little too dense for me. (I'm not a programmer by trade.) Agile Web Development with Rails can also be difficult for the early novice.

I though Learning Rails was easy to read. Also, Simply Rails 2.0 was good because it went through building a Digg-like app.

When you want to learn more than just Rails, I found Ruby for Rails gave me some good insight into the fundamentals.

Once you get comfortable with Rails, go get Metaprogrammning Ruby. I'm reading it now, and it's great. It'll help you understand all those gems that you're using and help you create 'magic' of your own.

Comment: thanks I have actually just ordered the metaprogramming ruby book as well, so I can understand some of the shortcuts that is done in the gems.

Comment: I agree. You will learn a lot from both rails 2 and rails 3 books.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation as you and I went with [Beginning Rails 3](http://apress.com/book/view/1430224339).

If you haven't been that impressed with APress books in the past (or anything that starts with "Beginning") don't let that scare you away.  I had a similar disposition but since there wasn't a lot of choices I just went with it.

I've been very surprised with the book in a positive way.  It keeps a good pace and has sidebars that explain things in more detail if you're interested to me,. The ordering of the book makes sense as the author starts with several chapters on Active Record then builds out from there.

If you want something you can starting reading now I'd defiantly say check it out.

Comment: Thanks I will order this book this week and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

All these are good and you might want to consider some Ruby books on metaprogramming because Rails has so much meta programming in it now that you should have a good basic understanding of what it is and how to use it. I suggest the Addison-Wesley Professional Ruby Series,
DESIGN PATTERNS IN RUBY by Russ Olsen. Here is a link to it on Amazon.
 [http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Ruby-Russ-Olsen/dp/0321490452](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321490452)